# Adding line after certain count of configurations lines with Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to add line in my karaf config file, Following is config snippet

```
wrapper.java.classpath.1=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/boot/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/wrapper/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=%KARAF_HOME%/system/org/ops4j/pax/logging/pax-logging-api/*/pax-logging-api-*.jar
```

Now i want that ansible script count all "wrapper.java.classpath.*" and insert new two line after above like

```
wrapper.java.classpath.4=%KARAF_HOME%/system/my*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.5=%KARAF_HOME%/system/my2*.jar
```

keep this in view its not necessary that next entry will be wrapper.java.classpath.4 count may change on base of installation.

i was looking into lineinfile but its not working as cant gather count with regexp

```
 - name: Adding classpath entries for my jar
      lineinfile: 
       dest: $KARAF_HOME/etc/wrapper.conf
       regexp: 'wrapper\.java\.classpath\.*' 
       line: 'wrapper.java.classpath.4=%KARAF_HOME%/system/my*.jar'
       backrefs: yes
```

Currently in shell script i am doing like below

```
NUM_CLASSPATH_ENTRIES=$(less ${WRAPPER_CONF_FILE} | grep wrapper\.java\.classpath | wc -l)

KARAF_MY_ENTRY="wrapper.java.classpath.$((NUM_CLASSPATH_ENTRIES+1))=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/my*.jar"
sed -i "/wrapper\.java\.classpath\.$NUM_CLASSPATH_ENTRIES.*/a $KARAF_MY_ENTRY" ${WRAPPER_CONF_FILE}
```

Comment: ① Use templates; ② Write a custom module.

Comment: It looks like you accepted @ilias-sp answer so this is just a question, but did you discard the idea of a template to keep the file updated?  My big concern with the solution provided is if someone/something updates the file and breaks the format you're expecting your playbook could produce invalid files.

Comment: @dan_linder I am currently refactoring existing shell script and also learning ansible. So will definitely look into it. Secondly its standard karaf configuration and highly chances it would not be change and i am running this script for first time installation.

Comment: lineinfile is **not** your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this playbook to count the lines of `wrapper.java.classpath` entries, and then append right after the last line the 2 more entries you need.

playbook:

```
  tasks:
    - name: cat file
      shell: cat testt.txt | grep '^wrapper.java.classpath'
      register: file_grep

    - name: find max number
      set_fact:
        max_number: "{{ max_number|default(0)|int + 1|int }}"
      loop: "{{ file_grep.stdout_lines }}"

    - name: Adding classpath entries for my jar
      blockinfile: 
        dest: testt.txt
        block: |
          wrapper.java.classpath.{{ max_number|int + 1|int }}=%KARAF_HOME%/system/my*.jar
          wrapper.java.classpath.{{ max_number|int + 2|int }}=%KARAF_HOME%/system/my2*.jar
        insertafter: "^(wrapper.java.classpath)(.+)$"
        backup: yes
```

sample config file (testt.txt in my tests):

```
wrapper.java.classpath.1=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/boot/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/wrapper/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=%KARAF_HOME%/system/org/ops4j/pax/logging/pax-logging-api/*/pax-logging-api-*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.4=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/boot/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.5=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/wrapper/*.jar
random config line 1
more random config line 1
and one last random line
```

run and result:

```
[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]# ansible-playbook testt.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [cat file] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [find max number] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=wrapper.java.classpath.1=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/boot/*.jar)
ok: [localhost] => (item=wrapper.java.classpath.2=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/wrapper/*.jar)
ok: [localhost] => (item=wrapper.java.classpath.3=%KARAF_HOME%/system/org/ops4j/pax/logging/pax-logging-api/*/pax-logging-api-*.jar)
ok: [localhost] => (item=wrapper.java.classpath.4=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/boot/*.jar)
ok: [localhost] => (item=wrapper.java.classpath.5=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/wrapper/*.jar)

TASK [Adding classpath entries for my jar] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0   

[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]# cat testt.txt
wrapper.java.classpath.1=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/boot/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/wrapper/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=%KARAF_HOME%/system/org/ops4j/pax/logging/pax-logging-api/*/pax-logging-api-*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.4=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/boot/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.5=%KARAF_BASE%/lib/wrapper/*.jar
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
wrapper.java.classpath.6=%KARAF_HOME%/system/my*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.7=%KARAF_HOME%/system/my2*.jar
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
random config line 1
more random config line 1
and one last random line[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]#
```

we are grepping to find the lines starting with `wrapper.java.classpath`, we count them, and then append (`insertafter`) the 2 lines after dynamically incrementing the "index" number to the next 2 values.

please check the `blockinfile` module documentation for configuring the `# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK` lines according to your needs.

hope it helps.

Comment: if we run cat testt.txt | grep '^wrapper.java.classpath' | wc -l we can get count and in setfact just do 1 increment rather than looping

Comment: you are right. i did with line by line inspection, because i thought we had to use the last line as argument in the `insertafter` clause of the `lineinblock` module, but it turns out the `insertafter` can be a regex, and changed it to this implementation :)